# Ubuntu 22.04: How to change login screen background?

Tags: 22.04, lock-screen, desktop-background

How to change the login screen background on Ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the login background images with these commands:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev-bin
wget -qO - https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/ubuntu-gdm-set-background/archive/main.tar.gz | tar zx --strip-components=1 ubuntu-gdm-set-background-main/ubuntu-gdm-set-background
sudo ./ubuntu-gdm-set-background --image IMAGE_PATH
```

replace IMAGE_PATH with the actual path of the image you want to set as background.

Its explained here : https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/login-screen-background-ubuntu-22-04/